# SwiftUI using Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I'm trying to use SwiftUI + Firebase Authentication via the email/password login. My question is, is there any way to append profile information to the user's authentication information when they create an account, or would I have to use Firebase Auth in tandem with Firestore or Firebase Database? I'm just trying to collect the user's first and last name and possibly city/state/country.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import Combine

class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<SessionStore, Never>()
    @Published var session: User? {didSet {self.didChange.send(self) }}
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

    func listen() {
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                self.session = User(uid: user.uid, email: user.email, displayName: user.displayName)
            } else {
                self.session = nil
            }
        })
    }

    func signUp(email: String, password: String, handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)
    }

    func signIn(email: String, password: String, handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)
    }

    func signOut() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            self.session = nil
        } catch {
            print("Error Signing Out")
        }
    }

    func unbind() {
        if let handle = handle {
            Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        unbind()
    }
}

struct User {
    var uid: String
    var email: String?
    var displayName: String?

    init(uid: String, email: String?, displayName: String?) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.email = email
        self.displayName = displayName
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I updated my question with my current code.

Comment: Not having experience with Firestore or Firebase I'd have to say you'd need to create the account with Firebase first and then store additional information in a separate table.

Comment: I think with `@Published` you don't need the `PassthroughSubject` anymore. It does it by itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firebase Authentication manages user authentication - while it does store additional information provided by some of the federated identity providers (such as profile picture URL), it isn't intended to be a profile management solution. If you'd like to store additional information about your users, you can implement this using Cloud Firestore or Firebase Realtime Database.

Please note that the [Custom Claims feature](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) is intended for managing advanced role management features - the [documentation actually discourages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#best_practices_for_custom_claims) developers from using this feature for storing additional user information, as custom claims are in fact stored in the ID token.

As @krjw correctly mentions, you don't need to use `PassthroughObject` when using `@Published`.

Here is a sample implementation:

```swift
// File: UserProfileRepository.swift
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct UserProfile: Codable {
  var uid: String
  var firstName: String
  var lastName: String
  var city: String
}

class UserProfileRepository: ObservableObject {
  private var db = Firestore.firestore()

  func createProfile(profile: UserProfile, completion: @escaping (_ profile: UserProfile?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    do {
      let _ = try db.collection("profiles").document(profile.uid).setData(from: profile)
      completion(profile, nil)
    }
    catch let error {
      print("Error writing city to Firestore: \(error)")
      completion(nil, error)
    }
  }

  func fetchProfile(userId: String, completion: @escaping (_ profile: UserProfile?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    db.collection("profiles").document(userId).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
      let profile = try? snapshot?.data(as: UserProfile.self)
      completion(profile, error)
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
// File: SessionStore.swift
import Foundation
import Combine
import Firebase

class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
  @Published var session: User?
  @Published var profile: UserProfile?

  private var profileRepository = UserProfileRepository()

  func signUp(email: String, password: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, city: String, completion: @escaping (_ profile: UserProfile?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("Error signing up: \(error)")
        completion(nil, error)
        return
      }

      guard let user = result?.user else { return }
      print("User \(user.uid) signed up.")

      let userProfile = UserProfile(uid: user.uid, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, city: city)
      self.profileRepository.createProfile(profile: userProfile) { (profile, error) in
        if let error = error {
          print("Error while fetching the user profile: \(error)")
          completion(nil, error)
          return
        }
        self.profile = profile
        completion(profile, nil)
      }
    }
  }

  func signIn(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ profile: UserProfile?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("Error signing in: \(error)")
        completion(nil, error)
        return
      }

      guard let user = result?.user else { return }
      print("User \(user.uid) signed in.")

      self.profileRepository.fetchProfile(userId: user.uid) { (profile, error) in
        if let error = error {
          print("Error while fetching the user profile: \(error)")
          completion(nil, error)
          return
        }

        self.profile = profile
        completion(profile, nil)
      }
    }
  }

  func signOut() {
    do {
      try Auth.auth().signOut()
      self.session = nil
      self.profile = nil
    }
    catch let signOutError as NSError {
      print("Error signing out: \(signOutError)")
    }
  }
}
```

For the UI:

```swift
// File: ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var firstName: String = ""
  @State var lastName: String = ""
  @State var city: String = ""
  @State var email: String = ""
  @State var password: String = ""
  @State var confirmPassword: String = ""

  @State var showSignUpForm = true
  @State var showDetails = false

  @ObservedObject var sessionStore = SessionStore()
  @State var profile: UserProfile?

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        if self.showSignUpForm {
          Form {
            Section {
              TextField("First name", text: $firstName)
                .textContentType(.givenName)
              TextField("Last name", text: $lastName)
                .textContentType(.familyName)
              TextField("City", text: $city)
                .textContentType(.addressCity)
            }
            Section {
              TextField("Email", text: $email)
                .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
              SecureField("Password", text: $password)
              SecureField("Confirm password", text: $confirmPassword)
            }
            Button(action: { self.signUp() }) {
              Text("Sign up")
            }
          }
          .navigationBarTitle("Sign up")
        }
        else {
          Form {
            TextField("Email", text: $email)
              .textContentType(.emailAddress)
              .autocapitalization(.none)
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
            Button(action: { self.signIn() }) {
              Text("Sign in")
            }
          }
          .navigationBarTitle("Sign in")
        }
        Button(action: { self.showSignUpForm.toggle() }) {
          Text(self.showSignUpForm ? "Have an account? Sign in instead." : "No account yet? Click here to sign up instead.")
        }
      }
      .sheet(isPresented: $showDetails) {
        UserProfileView(userProfile: self.profile ??  UserProfile(uid: "", firstName: "", lastName: "", city: ""))
      }
    }
  }

  func signUp() {
    sessionStore.signUp(email: self.email, password: self.password, firstName: self.firstName, lastName: self.lastName, city: self.city) { (profile, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("Error when signing up: \(error)")
        return
      }
      self.profile = profile
      self.showDetails.toggle()
    }
  }

  func signIn() {
    sessionStore.signIn(email: self.email, password: self.password) { (profile, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("Error when signing up: \(error)")
        return
      }
      self.profile = profile
      self.showDetails.toggle()
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

```swift
// File: UserProfileView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct UserProfileView: View {
  var userProfile: UserProfile
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Form {
        Text(userProfile.uid)
        Text(userProfile.firstName)
        Text(userProfile.lastName)
        Text(userProfile.city)
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("User \(userProfile.uid)")
    }
  }
}

struct UserProfileView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    let userProfile = UserProfile(uid: "TEST1234", firstName: "Peter", lastName: "Friese", city: "Hamburg")
    return UserProfileView(userProfile: userProfile)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[CombineFirebase](https://github.com/rever-ai/CombineFirebase) library will simplify your problem.
You can have simple signIn/stateChangePublisher flatMapped with your userProfilePublisher