# Function being called twice due to handlers, how to fix it so it's only called once?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I am new to Swift programming and am trying to understand the concept of handlers. My `saveDataToFirestore` function is being called twice - I'm pretty it's due to the completion handlers, but I can't figure it out

I have a button in the SignUpView that the user presses once they've inputted their information

```swift
struct SignUpView: View {
    @ObservedObject var user = UserViewModelTEMP()
...
    user.signUp(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email, password: password, reenterPassword: passwordReEnter) { (result, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            self.error = true
                        } else {
                            self.isSignedUp = true
                            self.password = ""
                        }
                    }
...
```

This is the ViewModel where first the `signUp` function is called, then the user's name and email is passed to another function so that their info can be save to the database

```swift
class UserViewModelTEMP : ObservableObject {
    @Published var user = [UserTEMP]()
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func signUp (firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, password: String, reenterPassword: String, handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback) {

        //Ensure that passwords match
        if reenterPassword != password {
            print("Passwords do not match") // make this into a popup
            return
        }
        //Authenticate with Firebase
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)

        // Save user data to Firestore
        saveDataToFirestore(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email)
    }
    
    func saveDataToFirestore(firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String) {
        print("entry one")
        // ensure user is signed in
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            print("entry 2")
            if let user = user {
                //if we have a user, create a new user model and save to Firebase
                print("Got user: \(user.uid)")
                let ref = self.db.collection("users").document(user.uid)
                ref.setData([
                    "first_name" : firstName,
                    "last_name"  : lastName,
                    "email"      : email
                ]) { err in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error adding document: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        print("Document added: \(ref.documentID)")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // when we don't have a user, set the session to nil
                //self.user = []
            }
        }
    }
```

Output looks like this

```
entry one
entry 2
Got user: <user_id_1>
Document added: <document>
entry 2
Got user: <user_id_2>
Document added: <document>
```

Side note, the user_ids in the output don't match, when they should (even if being called twice).

I am unsure how to fix this problem

Comment: I believe the saveDataToFirestore function should be inside of the createUser's then(); otherwise the auth state will change twice. Sorry, I've explained that poorly, what i mean is that "createUser" is an async function, so even before it's completed the listener you assign is active. So it triggers twice. And rather than a listener, wouldn't it be better to simply check the auth login info using firebase.auth().currentUser? It should give you the currently logged in user, Alternatively you can use auth().getUser(userId) to check if it's created.

Comment: @fabc thanks for the response. yes that makes sense on why the handler is being activated twice. I could use firebase.auth().currentUser? but the firebase docs said that you might get nil as the user if the auth object has not finished initializing - so I wanted to avoid that scenario entirely. However I guess in this instance the firebase.auth().currentUser? approach will work...
Can you explain what you mean by "should be inside of the createUser's then()" - where is the "then()"

Comment: Right, sorry, I'm used to thinking in terms of [java and/or javascript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#node.js_4), so that's kind of what my brain immediately went to. Basically: createUser is an async function, so it works a lot like a promise, meaning that you can perform a series of actions after receiving the result with [this kind of code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#sign_up_new_users), of which you can find a more thorought example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58964592/swiftui-using-firebase-authentication) Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah makes sense, thanks for the help! Life saver!

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I'm not sure if the issue is solved, and if it is, I don't think I deserve any credit, so you should probably post the solution in an answer and accept it so when people search for problems similar to the one that you have they can find the post more easily and see that it has a solution.