# How to access Firebase custom claims on client using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am attempting to access a user's custom claim on my iOS client in order to govern UI flow at login, following the [example in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client). However, when I try to integrate the coding example provided it causes multiple "Type 'Void' cannot conform to 'View'" errors in Xcode and does not compile.

In my code below, I've simply added a User object on which getIDTokenResult is called and I display a LoginView if that user is nil.

Why am I receiving these errors?

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject private var authenticationService = AuthenticationService()
  
  var body: some View {
    if let user = authenticationService.user {
      user.getIDTokenResult(completion: { (result, error) in
        guard let admin = result?.claims?["admin"] as? NSNumber else {
          // Show regular UI.
          ClientHomeView()
          return
        }
        if admin.boolValue {
          // Show admin UI.
          AdminHomeView()
        } else {
          // Show regular UI.
          ClientHomeView()
        }
      })
    }
    else {
      LoginView()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: All the firebase code should be in a ViewModel that is an ObservableObject. Make user, admin  Published variables

Comment: Hmm. How would I initialize the admin published variable in such a ViewModel?

Comment: As a nil, false, empty. Then update with the firebase values. What you are trying to do can’t be done in SwiftUI body’s, they are not async and would be making firebase calls every time the UI refreshes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58964592/swiftui-using-firebase-authentication

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=2o3euotz

Comment: Awesome. I've just got it working! My hierarchy is ContentView <- ContentViewModel <- AuthenticationService; in the deepest tier I make the async calls to firebase that fetch user and admin, then set them as published vars whose changes propagate to ContentView. Thank you @loremipsum !

Comment: I’m glad it worked. Make sure you are using StateObject too. When you initialize like in your example